# Most efficient way to loop through cells Column-wise

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I need to loop through each cell of a sheet, column-wise. I figured, converting a range to array is probably the most sensible option since I need to loop through 5000 rows across 68 columns.

I need to replace the Zeroes for over 5000 rows (in different positions) with a set value. The image below is what my table looks like, .the Zeroes would need to be replaced with the average values of the corresponding row

[image]

```vb
Sub searchreplace()    
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim col As Long
    Dim rng() As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim arr As Variant

    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)

    'lr = last row with data
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    With ActiveSheet
        lr = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        ' last column number MO66
        col = Range("BP1").Column

        'clumn with avg values
        colavg = Range("BQ1").Column

        'Debug.Print colavg

        'Define range
        'cells(row,col)!    

        'my range stored as an array
        rng = Range(Cells(3, 3), Cells(3, col + 6)). Value

        'looping through each value of the array
        For i = 1 To 70 '70 columns
            If rng(1, i) = 0 Then
                rng(1, i) = 5.34

            End If  
        Next i    
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You copied cells values into an array. You then modified that array. Obviously that does not affect the cells from which you copied the array. If you want to copy it back to cells, do the same in reverse, `Range(Cells(3, 3), Cells(3, col + 6)).Value = rng`.

Comment: edit and post some sample data and what are your expected results

Comment: Could you tell me how i can go about replacing values in the array when a condition is met and then later paste it into the range i got the array from?

Comment: @RicardoDiaz I just did

Comment: How do you calculate the average?

Comment: @the average of each row (66 values) has been calculated and is at the end of the said row. I would then need to replace the Zero wit this value which is right at the end of the Table

Comment: @GSerg I was ill prepared and a touch hasty, I got it to work using arrays,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the looked up value (0) appears only once per row

try this code and read the comments to adjust it to fit your needs

```
Public Sub ReplaceValueWithRowAverage()

    Dim evalRange As Range
    Dim evalCell As Range
    Dim targetCell As Range

    Dim targetValue As Double ' Adjust type to fit your needs
    Dim averageValue As Double ' Adjust type to fit your needs
    Dim evalSheetName As String
    Dim evalRangeAddress As String

    targetValue = 0
    evalSheetName = "Sheet1"
    evalRangeAddress = "A5:BP5232" ' This could be UsedRange with SpecialCells if sheet contains the target range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' Set the range to be evaluated
    Set evalRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(evalSheetName).Range(evalRangeAddress)

    ' Loop through each row
    For Each evalCell In evalRange.Columns(1).Cells

        ' Get the average value
        averageValue = evalCell.Offset(0, evalRange.Columns.Count - 1).Value2

        ' Find the target cell with value in row
        Set targetCell = evalCell.Resize(1, evalRange.Columns.Count - 1).Find(targetValue, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole)

        ' Replace the value with row average
        If Not targetCell Is Nothing Then targetCell.Value2 = averageValue

    Next evalCell

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "Finished"

End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

For replacing all the occurrences you can use Range.Replace method

```
Public Sub ReplaceValueWithRowAverage()

    Dim evalRange As Range
    Dim evalCell As Range
    Dim targetCell As Range

    Dim targetValue As Double ' Adjust type to fit your needs
    Dim averageValue As Double ' Adjust type to fit your needs
    Dim evalSheetName As String
    Dim evalRangeAddress As String

    targetValue = 0
    evalSheetName = "Sheet1"
    evalRangeAddress = "A5:BP5232" ' This could be UsedRange with SpecialCells if sheet contains the target range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' Set the range to be evaluated
    Set evalRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(evalSheetName).Range(evalRangeAddress)

    ' Loop through each row
    For Each evalCell In evalRange.Columns(1).Cells

        ' Get the average value
        averageValue = evalCell.Offset(0, evalRange.Columns.Count - 1).Value2

        ' Replace all ocurrences in row
        evalCell.Resize(1, evalRange.Columns.Count - 1).Cells.Replace What:=targetValue, Replacement:=averageValue, _
                          LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
                          SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False


    Next evalCell

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "Finished"

End Sub
```

I didn't use arrays as looping through each cell in this case works pretty fast

Note: If it works, remember to mark the answer to help others

Comment: Thanks, but it's possible that there are multiple zeroes in the row, so I'd have to check each cell colmunwise to see if it's equal to zero and then replace it!.

I tried using two for loops and CELLS, it works but it takes way too long for 5000 rows.

Comment: @neutronhammer See my Edit